# Search for filenames

Tags: batch-file

So I am trying to code an "A.I." through batch. The user will be able to enter in information, and the program will track keywords, and compile all data onto one text file in a specific folder. I have almost everything but a line that searches for all the filenames with a certain keyword. Here is an example. User: "Tell me EVERYTHING you know about GEORGE WASHINGTON" Program: Searches through memory for folder "George Washington" then gathers all the .txt files from that folder. It then types everything from those files to the user. Pls help, thanks :-)

Comment: Why are you doing this in batch? That's...not a suitable language! Your better option would be a language like Prolog which is designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: @RB -  For some reason, the most common first projects of people new to batch (especially those between the ages of 15 and 19) are a chatbot or an RPG. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
@echo off
set "foldertosearch=George Washington"
cd C:\
for /d /r %%a in ("%fodertosearch%") do (
echo found folder: %%a
cd %%a
)
for /f %%b in (*.txt) do (
echo found file: %%b
type "%%b"
)
pause
```

i recommend you to change the `C:\` of the 3rd line to a specific folder because i am not shure the `for /d` loop can handle a whole drive. use the where command instead.